# How can I scrape when server returns like this data?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I was trying to scrape a site using `Beautifulsoup` and python `requests` and the server returns response with content type  `text/javascript` with the `response body` containing this data:

```
Element.update("students", "<link href=\"https://somelinks.links\" media=\"screen\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" />\n\n<table class=\"gray_table_list\" align=\"center\" width=\"100%\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">\n    \n    <tr class=\"main_head back_ground_color\">\n    <td class=\"sl-col\">Sl No.</td>\n    <td class=\"set_border_right\"> Name</td>\n    <td class=\"set_border_right\">IDNo.</td>\n        \n        <td class=\"set_border_right\"></td>\n      </tr>\n      <tr class=\"tr-blank\">\n\n      \n      </tr>\n      \n        <tr class=\"row-bodd\">\n        <td class=\"set_border_right col-1\">\n            1\n          </td>\n\n          <td class=\"set_border_right col-1\">\n            <a href=\"/link/linkprofile/linkID1458556\">JOHN DOE  </a>\n          </td>\n\n          <td class=\"set_border_right col-1\">\n            ID12345\n          </td>\n\n          \n\n          <td class=\"set_border_right col-1\">\n            <a href=\"/link/linkprofile/linkID1458556\\">View profile</a>\n          </td>\n        </tr>\n      \n        <tr class=\"row-beven\">\n        <td class=\"set_border_right col-1\">\n            2\n          </td>\n\n          <td class=\"set_border_right col-1\">\n            <a href=\"/link/linkprofile/linkID1458556\\">Somename here  </a>\n          </td>\n\n          <td class=\"set_border_right col-1\">\n            ID45555\n          </td>\n\n          \n\n          <td class=\"set_border_right col-1\">\n            <a href=\"/link/linkprofile/linkID1458556\">View profile</a>\n          </td>\n        </tr>\n      \n        <tr class=\"row-bodd\">\n        <td class=\"set_border_right col-1\">\n            3\n          </td>\n\n          <td class=\"set_border_right col-1\">\n            <a href=\"/link/linkprofile/linkID1458556\\">name here  </a>\n          </td>\n\n          <td class=\"set_border_right col-1\">\n            ID7878\n          </td>\n\n          \n\n          <td class=\"set_border_right col-1\">\n            <a href=\"/link/linkprofile/linkID1458556\\">View profile</a>\n          </td>\n        </tr>\n\n </tr>\n      \n    \n    </table>\n  \n");
```

I have redacted the server response for self-containing the question. But how can I scrape that table in `Element.update`  and I also wanted to scrape `a tag` in the table I mean to extract the data `link/linkprofile/linkID1458556` from `<a href=\"/link/linkprofile/linkID1458556\">`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re` module to extract the HTML portion from this Javascript function and then parse it with BeautifulSoup normally. For example:

```py
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = """
Element.update("students", "<link href=\"https://somelinks.links\" media=\"screen\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" />\n\n<table class=\"gray_table_list\" align=\"center\" width=\"100%\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">\n    \n    <tr class=\"main_head back_ground_color\">\n    <td class=\"sl-col\">Sl No.</td>\n    <td class=\"set_border_right\"> Name</td>\n    <td class=\"set_border_right\">IDNo.</td>\n        \n        <td class=\"set_border_right\"></td>\n      </tr>\n      <tr class=\"tr-blank\">\n\n      \n      </tr>\n      \n        <tr class=\"row-bodd\">\n        <td class=\"set_border_right col-1\">\n            1\n          </td>\n\n          <td class=\"set_border_right col-1\">\n            <a href=\"/link/linkprofile/linkID1458556\">JOHN DOE  </a>\n          </td>\n\n          <td class=\"set_border_right col-1\">\n            ID12345\n          </td>\n\n          \n\n          <td class=\"set_border_right col-1\">\n            <a href=\"/link/linkprofile/linkID1458556\\">View profile</a>\n          </td>\n        </tr>\n      \n        <tr class=\"row-beven\">\n        <td class=\"set_border_right col-1\">\n            2\n          </td>\n\n          <td class=\"set_border_right col-1\">\n            <a href=\"/link/linkprofile/linkID1458556\\">Somename here  </a>\n          </td>\n\n          <td class=\"set_border_right col-1\">\n            ID45555\n          </td>\n\n          \n\n          <td class=\"set_border_right col-1\">\n            <a href=\"/link/linkprofile/linkID1458556\">View profile</a>\n          </td>\n        </tr>\n      \n        <tr class=\"row-bodd\">\n        <td class=\"set_border_right col-1\">\n            3\n          </td>\n\n          <td class=\"set_border_right col-1\">\n            <a href=\"/link/linkprofile/linkID1458556\\">name here  </a>\n          </td>\n\n          <td class=\"set_border_right col-1\">\n            ID7878\n          </td>\n\n          \n\n          <td class=\"set_border_right col-1\">\n            <a href=\"/link/linkprofile/linkID1458556\\">View profile</a>\n          </td>\n        </tr>\n\n </tr>\n      \n    \n    </table>\n  \n");
"""

html_doc = re.search(r'"students", "(.*?)"\);', s, flags=re.S).group(1)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

for tr in soup.select("tr"):
    tds = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tr.select("td")]
    print(*tds, sep="\t")
```

Prints:

```
Sl No.  Name    IDNo.

1       JOHN DOE        ID12345 View profile
2       Somename here   ID45555 View profile
3       name here       ID7878  View profile
```

---

EDIT: To get `<a>` links:

```py
for tr in soup.select("tr:has(a)"):
    print(tr.a["href"])
```

Prints:

```
/link/linkprofile/linkID1458556
/link/linkprofile/linkID1458556\
/link/linkprofile/linkID1458556\
```

Comment: I also wanted to scrape `a tag` in the table I mean to extract the data `link/linkprofile/linkID1458556` from `<a href=\"/link/linkprofile/linkID1458556\">` forexample